# I want to add a named variable in the output of the regular expression

Tags: python, regex, regex-group, python-re

I have a name in this format abc.xyz where abc is first Name and xyz is last Name. I want to create a regular expression which will give me output as `first name = 'abc' and last name= 'xyz'`

I have this regular expression: `re.findall(r'(\w+)\b.\b(\w+)',a)`  where `a=abc.xyz`
and output is `[("abc","xyz)"]` Is there anything that we can write in the regex itself which gives the output as like this `first name = 'abc' and last name= 'xyz'`

Comment: No; there are plenty of other tools that can format the result of your regex.

Comment: look at named groups https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#non-capturing-and-named-groups

Comment: try this  (?<name>'your regex')

Comment: @Ade_1 can you type it, I m not able to get it

Comment: Do you want to get the exact string `first name = 'abc' and last name= 'xyz'`?

Comment: @horcrux yes, in that format

Answer (score 2):

Try to use the format `(?P<name> expr)`.  For example:

```
(?P<first_name>\w+)\b.\b(?P<last_name>\w+)
```

[Regex Demo](http://(?P%3Cfirst_name%3E%5Cw%20)%5Cb.%5Cb(?P%3Clast_name%3E%5Cw%20))   (See the named group name at the right side)

**Note the correct syntax for Python is `(?P<name> expr)` (with a P) instead of just `(?<name> expr)` (without a P)**

Then you can make use of the method `groupdict()` to get a dictionary consisting of  all named groups, in the format `name : text`

Sample code:

```
m = re.match(r'(?P<first_name>\w+)\b.\b(?P<last_name>\w+)',a)
print(m.groupdict())

Output:
{'first_name': 'abc', 'last_name': 'xyz'}
```

Then you can use the following code to get what you want:

```
first_name = m.groupdict()['first_name']
last_name = m.groupdict()['last_name']
```

Comment: This looks good I tried this also, but i m hoping if i could find something so as to get in that format. though dictionary can be used as the interim output.

Comment: Note that as you are using Python, you may need a`P` between `(?` and `<`  (i.e. `(?P<name>` instead of just `(?<name>`.  Other regex flavor e.g. PHP does not need the P, but Python needs it.

Answer (score 1):

It is preferred to use grouping with search

```
your_regex= re.search(?<a>\w+)\b.\b(?<b>\w+)
your_regex.group('a')
your_regex.group('b')
```